# Install python ssdeep wrapper on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, fuzzy-comparison

I am running python `2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

pip install ssdeep

```
...
_ssdeep_cffi_8a9054b9x627c7d55.c
ssdeep\__pycache__\_ssdeep_cffi_8a9054b9x627c7d55.c(209) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fuzzy.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jlevas~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jzdbfu\ssdeep\setup.py", line 123, in <module>
    ext_package="ssdeep",
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 180, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 291, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
...
```

I tried with easy_install and even install from the zip (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssdeep) version 3.1.1 (for that I used cygwin `python setup.py install`

But I always get the same error, `fuzzy.h` can't be opened.